# Как сделать панель с кнопками и выпадающим списком для кнопок, которые не поместились в панели?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать панель с кнопками так, чтобы при уменьшении панели (окна) не помещающиеся кнопки прятались в кнопку в этой же панели, при клике на которую, появлялся бы выпадающий список со скрытыми кнопками? А при расширении, они бы обратно появлялись на панели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то ты ищешь вот такое меню

```js
var $nav = $('.greedy-nav');
var $btn = $('.greedy-nav button');
var $vlinks = $('.greedy-nav .visible-links');
var $hlinks = $('.greedy-nav .hidden-links');

var breaks = [];

function updateNav() {
  
  var availableSpace = $btn.hasClass('hidden') ? $nav.width() : $nav.width() - $btn.width() - 30;

  // The visible list is overflowing the nav
  if($vlinks.width() > availableSpace) {

    // Record the width of the list
    breaks.push($vlinks.width());

    // Move item to the hidden list
    $vlinks.children().last().prependTo($hlinks);

    // Show the dropdown btn
    if($btn.hasClass('hidden')) {
      $btn.removeClass('hidden');
    }

  // The visible list is not overflowing
  } else {

    // There is space for another item in the nav
    if(availableSpace > breaks[breaks.length-1]) {

      // Move the item to the visible list
      $hlinks.children().first().appendTo($vlinks);
      breaks.pop();
    }

    // Hide the dropdown btn if hidden list is empty
    if(breaks.length < 1) {
      $btn.addClass('hidden');
      $hlinks.addClass('hidden');
    }
  }

  // Keep counter updated
  $btn.attr("count", breaks.length);

  // Recur if the visible list is still overflowing the nav
  if($vlinks.width() > availableSpace) {
    updateNav();
  }

}

// Window listeners

$(window).resize(function() {
    updateNav();
});

$btn.on('click', function() {
  $hlinks.toggleClass('hidden');
});

updateNav();
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #999;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
}
.greedy-nav {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
}
.greedy-nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.greedy-nav a:hover {
  color: #006cff;
}
.greedy-nav button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #006cff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.greedy-nav button:hover {
  background-color: #006cff;
}
.greedy-nav button::after {
  content: attr(count);
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -16px;
  top: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #006cff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.greedy-nav button:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1.075);
}
.greedy-nav .hamburger {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: auto;
}
.greedy-nav .hamburger:before,
.greedy-nav .hamburger:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
}
.greedy-nav .hamburger:before {
  top: -8px;
}
.greedy-nav .hamburger:after {
  bottom: -8px;
}
.greedy-nav .visible-links {
  display: inline-table;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.greedy-nav .visible-links li {
  display: table-cell;
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
.greedy-nav .hidden-links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
}
.greedy-nav .hidden-links li {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #006cff;
}
.greedy-nav .visible-links li:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.greedy-nav .visible-links li:first-child a {
  color: #006cff !important;
}
.greedy-nav .hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='greedy-nav'>
<button><div class="hamburger"></div></button>
  <ul class='visible-links'>
    <li><a target="_blank" href='https://github.com/lukejacksonn/GreedyNav'>Greedy</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>navigation</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>that</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>handles</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>overflowing</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>menu</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>elements</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>effortlessly</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='hidden-links hidden'></ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

В верстке нужно создать эти кнопки как в панели, так и вне её.
Затем, с помощью медиавыражений сделать так, чтобы при определенной ширине экрана кнопки, находящиеся вне панели, скрывались, но появлялись те, которые вне её.

Answer (score 0):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/ может поможет, хорошая статья.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).